# Favicon Malfunctioned after adding Google Adsense

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, favicon

Not sure if you've seen this one but I'm stomped so here it goes: I've partnered with google and as a requirement I placed the google adsense code on my page to be verified and able to display ads.

However, before partnering up I had a fully functioning favicon displayed on my website on all pages, posts, and my website links. Now, after partnering up, My favicon is not displaying like before. The google blogger favicon has now taken over the place of my favicon and I can't get it back no matter how I try.

Could it be the script code that I had to copy in the  php and sidebar widget area?

By the way, I deleted the code from the `<head>` php area and that didn't work. I'm really confused. What's really weird is that the Contact page is the only page that still shows my favicon like it's supposed to show on all my pages esp homepage. Please checkout my site sve-accountingandtaxes.com to see if you can see anything looking out of place with favicon?

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue, but you'll need to your showcase your **existing code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to really be able to help. It would help to know what favicon files exist on your site, along with what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve the problem. For example, have you re-added the old favicons and cleared your cache?

Comment: Thanks for responding Obsidian; I tried your suggestion and completely cleared the cache and tried to re-add my favicon. I am getting an error message saying there is an error loading favicon.ico file. But that's all the info from the error message. I also noticed the .ico files on my site are greyed out (usually I can see the picture thumbnail image). However, my other files i.e. png and jpeg i can still see those as usual with the thumbnail image showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I go to your homepage, I do not see the favicon displayed on the browser tab like I normally would. But when I go to https://www.sve-accountingandtaxes.com/favicon.ico I do not see a favicon displayed on the page, either. I just see a completely white page. For comparison, when I go to https://www.google.com/favicon.ico I see the image (small) in the center of the page.

Perhaps it accidentally got deleted and needs to be uploaded again.

Comment: Thanks for responding Amethyst; after completely clearing the cache and following the https://www.sve-accountingandtaxes.com/favicon.ico link I now see a blank page too. And I went to the google link to see what it should look like to verify and I understand now what should be showing if my favicon is working properly. Whenever I try re-loading the favicon.ico file I get a message saying error loading favicon.ico file. At least the blogger favicon is no longer showing on my side. Oh, when I am logged into the back end of my wordpress I can see the favicon displayed; but not when logged out.

Comment: I just reload the image again and now I can find it on https://www.sve-accountingandtaxes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/favicon.ico. However, I still cannot see it when logged out. And, the favicon that I am able to see when logged in is actually a PNG attachment. The theme I'm using recommends uploading at least a 512 x 512 size attachment for the favicon (under the Site Identity section).

Comment: You can either upload it through your wordpress theme, the way you mentioned. Or you can upload it directly to your web host in the root directory as favicon.ico. If that's still not working and only showing when you're logged in, I'd call your web host and see if there is a known issue.

Comment: Amethyst - thank you! It worked. I had to actually upload it directly to my web host root directory even though the wordpress theme customization worked before. And searching online resulted in the same demos showing how to load a favicon through the wordpress theme. But, yes, the web host root directory was the way to go. Thanks again for all your help.